# Where does INumeric come from?

Tags: interface

I see kudos to INumeric and blog posts that state how to simulate the features in its absence from a language (e.g. [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/lucabol/archive/2009/02/05/simulating-inumeric-with-dynamic-in-c-4-0.aspx)
 )

But in what language/s does this  INumeric goodness originate from? In other words in what languages would I find examples of INumeric?

I Googled its name and didn't come up with useful results about origin or examples. But I'm sure somebody here knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out [INumeric](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.PowerPack/Microsoft.FSharp.Math.type_INumeric-1.html) is found in the [F# Power Pack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) and not in the plain, vanilla F# installation. No wonder it took a bit of digging. Got some help from [here](http://blog.matthewdoig.com/?p=112) and [here](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/13759.aspx)